# GTFS Query to list all departure and arrival times between two stop names

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

I'm working with GTFS structure for the first time and am having trouble with the queries.  I've got the transit data into mysql tables, and am free to query them, but I feel like I'm doing far too many queries and for loops to get the simplest info.

What I'd like to get in a single query is all the departure times and arrival times between two known stops, possibly identified by name.

Here is what I have so far, which involves a query, followed by looping through each trip_id to find the departure and arrival station info + times.

**Query 1**:

Show all departure times from a particular origin station, going in a particular direction.  Result will give departure times and trip_ids.

```
SELECT t.trip_id, trip_headsign, departure_time, direction_id, s.stop_name 
FROM stops s, routes r, stop_times st, calendar c, trips t 
WHERE departure_time > "00:00:00" and departure_time < "23:59:59" 
AND r.route_id=1 and s.stop_id = 42 
AND s.stop_id = st.stop_id 
AND st.trip_id = t.trip_id   
AND c.service_id = t.service_id   
AND c.monday=1 and direction_id=1;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+---------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+
| trip_id | trip_headsign | departure_time | direction_id | stop_name |
+---------+---------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+
| 5671498 | Grand Central | 04:43:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671501 | Grand Central | 05:13:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671504 | Grand Central | 05:43:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671506 | Grand Central | 06:08:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671507 | Grand Central | 06:32:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671513 | Grand Central | 06:53:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671516 | Grand Central | 07:18:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671519 | Grand Central | 07:40:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671521 | Grand Central | 08:03:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671523 | Grand Central | 08:32:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671525 | Grand Central | 08:58:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671526 | Grand Central | 09:27:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671529 | Grand Central | 10:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671532 | Grand Central | 11:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671535 | Grand Central | 12:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671537 | Grand Central | 13:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671540 | Grand Central | 14:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671542 | Grand Central | 15:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671543 | Grand Central | 16:22:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671547 | Grand Central | 17:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671550 | Grand Central | 18:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671552 | Grand Central | 19:26:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671554 | Grand Central | 20:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671556 | Grand Central | 21:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671557 | Grand Central | 22:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
| 5671559 | Croton-Harmon | 23:24:00       |            1 | Garrison  |
+---------+---------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+
```

**Query 2**:

Give me all the stops on a particular trip along with their arrival times, use trip_id from last query:

```
SELECT s.stop_id,stop_lat, stop_lon, stop_name, arrival_time, stop_sequence 
FROM stop_times st JOIN stops s ON s.stop_id=st.stop_id 
WHERE trip_id=5671521;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+-----------+------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+
| stop_id | stop_lat  | stop_lon   | stop_name        | arrival_time | stop_sequence |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+
|      51 | 41.705839 | -73.937946 | Poughkeepsie     | 07:31:00     |             1 |
|      49 | 41.587448 | -73.947226 | New Hamburg      | 07:41:00     |             2 |
|      46 | 41.504007 | -73.984528 | Beacon           | 07:50:00     |             3 |
|      43 | 41.415283 | -73.958090 | Cold Spring      | 07:58:00     |             4 |
|      42 | 41.381780 | -73.947202 | Garrison         | 08:03:00     |             5 |
|      40 | 41.332601 | -73.970426 | Manitou          | 08:08:00     |             6 |
|      39 | 41.285962 | -73.930420 | Peekskill        | 08:17:00     |             7 |
|      37 | 41.246259 | -73.921884 | Cortlandt        | 08:22:00     |             8 |
|      33 | 41.189903 | -73.882394 | Croton-Harmon    | 08:32:00     |             9 |
|       4 | 40.805157 | -73.939149 | Harlem-125th St. | 09:09:00     |            10 |
|       1 | 40.752998 | -73.977056 | Grand Central    | 09:22:00     |            11 |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+
```

What I'd really like is a list of departure times and arrival times between two stops, such as this theorized result:

```
+---------+----------------+----------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| trip_id | departure_stop | departure_time | direction | arrival_stop  | arrival_time |
+---------+----------------+----------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| 5671521 | Garrison       | 08:03:00       |         1 | Grand Central | 09:22:00     |
| 5671522 | Garrison       | 08:32:00       |         1 | Grand Central | 09:51:00     |    
...etc...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply joining data together, joining to `stops` twice for start and end stop and joining to `stop_times` twice for start and end stop_times,
the only thing i am unsure about is where `direction_id` comes from.
try the below query.
At the very end of the query, you can specify `start_s.stop_id` and `end_s.stop_id` which represents the two stops you're querying data about.

```
SELECT t.trip_id,
       start_s.stop_name as departure_stop,
       start_st.departure_time,
       direction_id as direction,
       end_s.stop_name as arrival_stop,
       end_st.arrival_time
FROM
trips t INNER JOIN calendar c ON t.service_id = c.service_id
        INNER JOIN routes r ON t.route_id = r.route_id
        INNER JOIN stop_times start_st ON t.trip_id = start_st.trip_id
        INNER JOIN stops start_s ON start_st.stop_id = start_s.stop_id
        INNER JOIN stop_times end_st ON t.trip_id = end_st.trip_id
        INNER JOIN stops end_s ON end_st.stop_id = end_s.stop_id
WHERE c.monday = 1 
  AND direction_id = 1
  AND start_st.departure_time > "00:00:00" AND start_st.departure_time < "23:59:59" 
  AND r.route_id = 1
  AND start_s.stop_id = 42
  AND end_s.stop_id = 1
```

I tried looking up GTFS structure example from [this link](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/examples/gtfs-feed) and i couldn't find anything on `direction_id`

To specify stop names instead of `AND start_s.stop_id = 42 AND end_s.stop_id = 1`
just use `AND start_s.stop_name = 'Garrison' AND end_s.stop_name = 'Grand Central'`

Comment: direction_id is either 0 or 1, to specify direction (north/south; east/west) on the train line.  Trains run both directions using the same stops, so without this there is no way of knowing which direction the result is for.

Comment: Darn, you beat me - but only by 18 months.