# Sample GTFS SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

I've converted **GTFS** data into a **MySQL DB** using [OpenTransitTools](https://github.com/OpenTransitTools/gtfsdb).

I'm just getting started with **GTFS** and wanted some help with some basic SQL queries like:

- Given the current time, list the positions of all vehicles along a particular route. *I'm not sure if it's possible to estimate the lat/long for the point between two stops given a route and its shape? Maybe this is more complex or not required.*
- List all stop locations (lat/long) along a particular route.
- List all transfer locations with options (lat/long) along a particular route.

It would also be cool to get some more sample common SQL queries or a cookbook of basic to complex query examples.

Thank you!

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212588/gtfs-query-to-list-all-departure-and-arrival-times-between-two-stop-names?rq=1